# Reroute realm network for jest test locally, error when call realm function

Tags: realm

**Goal**

Jest test react-native application that using realm sync as database completely local without using internet connection nor hit realm sync server.

**My App Logic**

User login with realm user credential and sync data from device to the realm server

**How I did it**

First I reroute the routine that opening the realm connection so that when the code runs in the jest-test environment it will open the local file realm instead of realm sync.

Then by mocking `realm-network-transport` module I intercept any request attempt to the remote realm server (mongo stitch server) so it will serve the response from a designated static response I prepared.

It is also applied to user function call as at the end realm function call will use HTTP request using `realm-network-transport` module

**The Problem**

All is working fine prior to using realmjs v10.1.2,but after using v10.1.2 only authentication routine is works, function call throwing error with this workaround (things do works normal in normal run)

The error reported is

```
JS value must be of type 'object', got (undefined)
    at func (.../node_modules/realm/lib/user.js:34:37)
    ...
```

the code pointed by the error is

```
callFunction(name, args, service = undefined) {
    return promisify(cb => this._callFunction(name, this._cleanArgs(args), service, cb));
},
```

i tried to console.log `this, name, args, and service`, it yield

```
{} clientAvailableOutletPosid [...function argument...] undefined
```

which i guess will go to `/node_modules/realm/src/js_user.hpp` line 354

```
template<typename T>
void UserClass<T>::call_function(ContextType ctx, ObjectType this_object, Arguments& args, ReturnValue &) {
    args.validate_count(4);
    auto user = get_internal<T, UserClass<T>>(ctx, this_object);

    auto name = Value::validated_to_string(ctx, args[0], "name");
    auto call_args_js = Value::validated_to_array(ctx, args[1], "args");
    auto service = Value::is_undefined(ctx, args[2])
            ? util::none
            : util::Optional<std::string>(Value::validated_to_string(ctx, args[2], "service"));
    auto callback = Value::validated_to_function(ctx, args[3], "callback");

    auto call_args_bson = Value::to_bson(ctx, call_args_js);

    user->m_app->call_function(
        *user,
        name,
        call_args_bson.operator const bson::BsonArray&(),
        service,
        Function::wrap_callback_error_first(ctx, this_object, callback,
            [] (ContextType ctx, const util::Optional<bson::Bson>& result) {
                REALM_ASSERT_RELEASE(result);
                return Value::from_bson(ctx, *result);
            }));
}
```

Where to go from here?

Comment: I faced the same error. Locally the node app worked, on the server it didn't. I tried several node versions on both systems. Setting the dependency version of realm from "^10.1.2" to "10.1.1" and running npm install again solved the problem for me. Thanks for the info